# Split string into integers and operands

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, calculator

I'm trying to make a basic calculator in java by using a scanner to have a string input and then split the string into numbers and operators and then do the equation.

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter equation:\n");
        String equation = scanner.nextLine();

        for (char i = 0; i < equation.length(); i++) {
            if (i == '+') {
                System.out.println("add");
            } else if (i == '-') {
                System.out.println("minus");
            } else if (i == '*') {
                System.out.println("times");
            } else if (i == '/') {
                System.out.println("divide");
            }
        }
```

I have this method where I can request an equation, turn it into a string and then display the operator.
But I have no clue where to go from here. I have looked at regex to try split it but this doesnt seem possible.
Any help be great! Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are currently comparing your index `i` to the tokens you are searching for. You probably want to use `equation.charAt(i)` to get the corresponding character from the string. Yes you can definitely identify operators and numbers using regular expressions. Have you completed the standard tutorial on them at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/? It's worth doing that and having a go yourself before asking a question here.

Comment: It is possible with regexes. For example, you could use `([0-9]+) ?([+-*/]) ? ([0-9]+)`. The first and last group are the operands and the middle group is the operator.

Comment: Once you've got parsing the string down, you may want to look at the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) for how to evaluate the equation.